# Enabling cors on Sails.js app and NGINX reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, cors, sails.js, reverse-proxy

Sails.js cors configuration

```
module.exports.cors = {

    /***************************************************************************
    *                                                                          *
    * Allow CORS on all routes by default? If not, you must enable CORS on a   *
    * per-route basis by either adding a "cors" configuration object to the    *
    * route config, or setting "cors:true" in the route config to use the      *
    * default settings below.                                                  *
    *                                                                          *
    ***************************************************************************/

    allRoutes: true,

    /***************************************************************************
    *                                                                          *
    * Which domains which are allowed CORS access? This can be a               *
    * comma-delimited list of hosts (beginning with http:// or https://) or    *
    * "*" to allow all domains CORS access.                                    *
    *                                                                          *
    ***************************************************************************/

    origin: '*',

    /***************************************************************************
    *                                                                          *
    * Allow cookies to be shared for CORS requests?                            *
    *                                                                          *
    ***************************************************************************/

    // credentials: true,

    /***************************************************************************
    *                                                                          *
    * Which methods should be allowed for CORS requests? This is only used in  *
    * response to preflight requests (see article linked above for more info)  *
    *                                                                          *
    ***************************************************************************/

    methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',

    /***************************************************************************
    *                                                                          *
    * Which headers should be allowed for CORS requests? This is only used in  *
    * response to preflight requests.                                          *
    *                                                                          *
    ***************************************************************************/

    headers: 'content-type, Authorization'

  };
```

I Also tried setting up nginx

This are the logs -> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you testing directly or through nginx? Because both scenarios will be different. Also post your nginx config

Comment: I've got a sails app behind nginx reverse proxy with CORS enabled (and functioning) on certain routes. Can you be more precise about which calls you are allowing access to? The client-side of CORS also has to be set up a certain way, maybe this is what you are missing.

Comment: headers: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type' try adding this